# How do I link an application to usr/local/bin so I can call it globally in the terminal. Mac

Tags: bash, macos, path, ls

I installed a new code editor. Sublime 3. 
I want to be able to open Sublime from the command terminal so I can use commands like

```
Editor .
```

To open a code project whose directory I am in.

To do this I tried linking the Sublime App to my 'usr/local/bin' in the following ways.

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime Text.app /usr/local/bin
ln -s /Applications/Sublime Text /usr/local/bin
```

'Sublime' now shows up in the '/usr/local/bin' directory, however the following commands don't work.

```
cd /path/code_folder
Sublime . 
Sublime Text.app . 
Sublime Text .
```

They all return

```
-bash: Sublime: command not found
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You linked to the wrong thing. `Sublime Text.app` is really a directory, you want to symlink to the actual binary:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/
```

This is almost a verbatim copy/paste from the [documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html). I kept the name `subl` though you could obviously easily use a different name.

Notice also the correct use of quotes; you created a symlink `Text.app` and another called `Sublime`, neither of which currently points to a valid location. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Symlinks are slightly pesky in that the system doesn't warn, or indeed check at all, whether the target exists when you create one. It wold be pretty pointless in any event, as the destination could go away at any time later anyway. But it's surprising and annoying when you first discover this.

Comment: Tangentially, notice that you want the symlink in `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/bin`; the latter is reserved for the OS, and should not be tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

Download Sublime Text for Mac.

In your Downloads directory, double-click on Sublime Text.dmg to open it.

Drag Submlime Text 2.app into your Applications folder.

Run below command in your terminal.

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Now open file in current directory using subl filename.

Comment: Minor nitpick; the OP is asking about version 3.